# Take control of scrollView mid animation of contentOffset

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiscrollview

When I tap my `scrollView` it activates a `UITapGestureRecognizer` that animates the `contentOffset` for about 2 seconds. How could I allow the user to interrupt the animation and take full control of the `scrollView` again when they drag? Right now the user has to wait until the end of the animation to start interacting with the `scrollView` again.

Note: `self` refers to the `scrollView`

Tap set up:

```
let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "subtleBounce:")
        singleTap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        self.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
```

So when the user taps:

```
func subtleBounce(gesture : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let originalFrame = self.frame

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.5, initialSpringVelocity: 1.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: {
            self.contentOffset.y -= 10.0

            }, completion: {
                Void in
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.1, initialSpringVelocity: 3.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: { 
               self.contentOffset.y += 10.0 }, completion: { Void in

                })
        })
    }
```

So the code above works as intended.

Here is what I've tried to stop the animation and give the user control of the scrollView again:

```
let drag = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "stopScrollAnimation:")
        drag.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        self.addGestureRecognizer(drag)
```

and elsewhere:

```
func stopScrollAnimation(gesture : UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        self.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        self.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), animated: false)
    }
```

However this DOES NOT work as intended. The animation still controls the scrollView and the user cannot interact with it.

If you want an example what I mean, look at the iOS7/8 lockscreen. After tapping the screen it also starts an animation. The user can take control of the scrollView mid animation however.

edit: accepting answers in swift or obj-c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [AllowUserInteraction](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewAnimationOptions) to your animation options.